# Android Spinner populated from CursorLoader doesn’t show selected item

Tags: android, spinner, android-cursorloader

I have 2 spinners in a single fragment. The second one which is populated from List shows the numbers 1 to 100 and the value after I selected it.

The first spinner gets populated from a CursorLoader. When I click on the spinner it shows the list of subjects correcty but when I select a subject, this selected subject doesn’t appear. (I have included screen shots to show what I mean).

My fragment code and fragment layout below:

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        rootView =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_user_input, container, false);

        subjectSpinner = rootView.findViewById(R.id.subjects_spinner);
        subjectAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                getActivity(),
                R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
                null,
                new String[]{ProgrammeCourseContract.SubjectsEntry.COLUMN_TITLE},
                new int[]{R.id.subject_spinner_name});

        subjectAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.subject_spinner_item);
        subjectAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        subjectSpinner.setAdapter(subjectAdapter);

        marksSpinner = rootView.findViewById(R.id.marks_spinner);
        marksAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Integer>(
                getActivity(),
                R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
                getMarks()
        );

        marksAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.mark_spinner_item);
        marksSpinner.setAdapter(marksAdapter);

        return rootView;

    }

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/user_input_root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:context="com.wernerraubenheimer.ujcp.fragments.UserInputFragment">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <!-- Subjects Spinner Dropdown -->
        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/subjects_spinner"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
            android:prompt="@string/subject_spinner_prompt" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <!-- Marks Spinner Dropdown -->
        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/marks_spinner"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
            android:prompt="@string/subject_spinner_prompt" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

mark_spinner_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mark_spinner_name"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:padding="5dp"/>
```

subject_spinner_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/subject_spinner_name"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:padding="5dp"/>
```

[image: CursorLoader works - list of subjects show]

[image: Selected subject doesn't show]

Comment: I guess the cursorloader code is also needed to understand, as these two spinners you posted are totally symmetric

Comment: Yes, please see my onCreateView answer that I posted below.

Comment: please don't answer yourself with another question, just append that onCreateView() code in your former question. Otherwise it's difficult to reply

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the SimpleCursorAdapter. Made sure that the TextView ID I was specifying is in the same layout referenced there. Make sure to reference the same layout file where my TextView is included.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    rootView =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_user_input, container, false);

    subjectSpinner = rootView.findViewById(R.id.subjects_spinner);
    subjectAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
            getActivity(),
            R.layout.subject_spinner_item,
            null,
            new String[]{ProgrammeCourseContract.SubjectsEntry.COLUMN_TITLE},
            new int[]{R.id.subject_spinner_name});

    subjectAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    subjectSpinner.setAdapter(subjectAdapter);


    marksSpinner = rootView.findViewById(R.id.marks_spinner);
    marksAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Integer>(
            getActivity(),
            R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
            getMarks()
    );

    marksAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.mark_spinner_item);
    marksSpinner.setAdapter(marksAdapter);

    return rootView;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

From docs:

> [SimpleCursorAdapter is] an easy adapter to map columns from a cursor to TextViews

and its contructor is

```
SimpleCursorAdapter (Context context, 
            int layout, 
            Cursor c, 
            String[] from, 
            int[] to, 
            int flags)
```

(I think you're using a deprecated one) but I can't get what you're mapping to what. Also, I can't see `R.id.subject_spinner_name` in your layout, while doc states:

> to    int: The views that should display column in the "from" parameter.
>   These should all be TextViews. The first N views in this list are
>   given the values of the first N columns in the from parameter. Can be
>   null if the cursor is not available yet.

To me, it looks like you should simply use another ArrayListAdapter, because the final purpose is similar to the right spinner's one. Am I right?